# What are these Google Drive MIME types?

Tags: google-drive-api

The Google Drive API documents a [list of supported MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/mime-types).  I am confused by this subset of that list:

- application/vnd.google-apps.audio
- application/vnd.google-apps.kix
- application/vnd.google-apps.photo
- application/vnd.google-apps.script
- application/vnd.google-apps.sites
- application/vnd.google-apps.unknown
- application/vnd.google-apps.video

These MIME types are not reflected in any item I have been able to add to Google Drive either via the desktop agent or via the web interface.  How would one create a file on Google Drive with, for example, the MIME type "application/vnd.google-apps.photo"? Is it only possible through the API?  Is that even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create files with these mime types. You can either create blank files or convert an existing file format to one of them during the upload. For example, if you have a CSV file, setting convert flag to true will create a new `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` file. This is an example for the Java client:

```
service.files().insert(metaData, csvFileContent).setConvert(true).execute();
```

You can always create blank files with these mime types.

Comment: Thank you, Burcu.  I am still having difficulty, though.

If I upload a CSV with convert=true, I get a spreadsheet just like you said.  

But if I upload a JPEG with convert=true, I get a document with type "application/vnd.google-apps.document".  How can I make an item with type "application/vnd.google-apps.photo"?

If I upload an MP3 with convert=true, I get a file with MIME type (audio/mpeg).  How can I make it (or something like it) have MIME Type of "application/vnd.google-apps.audio"?

Thanks.

Comment: @JohnBrayton Did you find any solution for that ?